# Syntax for TypeScript interfaces

Tags: typescript

I'm still quite new to TypeScript and I have the following syntax that confuses me a bit.

```
export interface FileDialogFactory {
    (props: FileDialogProps): FileDialog;
}
```

As far as I understand it, this is an interface that can later be used by some variable. Inside of this interface is a defined variable name named props that has the type FileDialogProps. What I don't understand is the meaning of the colon ":" and the the following `FileDialog`. So what type is the variable `props` supposed to be? Is it `FileDialogProps` or is it `FileDialog`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an interface that contains a function signature. A function that takes an argument of type `FileDialogProps` and returns a `FileDialog`. So a variable of this type will be callable:

```
let fact:FileDialogFactory;
let dialog = fact(props);
```

An interface can have multiple function signatures, these will act as overloads and any of them is callable with the same rules typescript applies to function overload resolution:

```
export interface FileDialogFactory {
    (props: FileDialogProps): FileDialog;
    (props: FileDialogProps, isOpen: boolean): FileDialog;
}
let fact:FileDialogFactory;
let dialog = fact(props);
let dialog2 = fact(props, true); // also ok
```

Comment: So, the function has no name. It's just called `()`, right? And, following your example code, when I call `fact(props)`, I call the default function that takes a `FileDialogProps` parameter and has to return the type `FileDialog`, right? So, am I right to say, that there can only be one such anonymous function?

Comment: @Socrates no, such an interface can have multiple function signatures, they will act as overloads.

Comment: Ok, so am I right to say, that those multiple function signatures are still anonymous? They don't have a name such as `doSomething(props: FileDialogProps)`. If there is more than one like this, the differentiation is done by the type of the argument and the return type, right?

Comment: @Socrates Yes, I added an example, to ilustrate, make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The `FileDialogFactory` interface you have in the code sample contains a *function* definition in which there is a single parameter `props` of type `FileDialogProps` and the function returns an instance of interface/type `FileDialog`.